# Maven Spring MVC : Background image not recognising

Tags: css, maven, spring-mvc, url, netbeans

I am working on a spring mvc maven project, and here is my file structure :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSW66.png

```
 body  {
        background: url("/WEB-INF/Images/Image/tests.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

This is my css to display the background image. But for some reason, the image is not getting displayed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must tell spring what path to access static resources in the xml config

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/res/**"></mvc:resources>
"resources" is the folder in the project, "res" is the request mapping

[image: Directories]